# Trying to update single row in SQL database using LINQ to SQL using a WCF service

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, wcf-data-services

What I'm trying to do is create a method using a WCF service to go through One database ( transactions) grab everything from the table which has todays date, then add them to my daily sales table which will have one row per date displaying the profit, the daily takings, the expenses, etc.

I've tried to do it like this

```
        public void CalculateProfit(string Date)
        {

            decimal takings = 0;// not needed
            decimal Expenses = 0;// not needed
            using (transactionClassDataContext cont = new transactionClassDataContext())
            { 
                int counter = 0;
                DailySale d = new DailySale();
                var query = (from q in cont.DailySales where q.Date.Equals(Date) select q);
                var query2 = (from r in cont.Transactions where r.Date.Equals(Date) select r);
                foreach (var z in query)
                {
                    counter++;

                }
                if (counter>0)
                {

                        foreach (var y in query2)
                        {

                            takings = takings + y.Price;
                            Expenses = Expenses + 0;

                            d.Expenses += 0;
                            d.Takings += y.Price;
                            d.Profit = d.Takings - d.Expenses;
                            d.Date = Date;

                            cont.DailySales.InsertOnSubmit(d);// update the value
                            cont.SubmitChanges();

                        }              
                }
                else
                {

                    d.Date = Date;
                    cont.DailySales.InsertOnSubmit(d);// if there isnt an entry for todays date, add one
                    cont.SubmitChanges();
                }

            }

        }


    }
}
```

But all it does is throw this error "Cannot add an entity that already exists."

Most similar questions have said I need to create a new instance of d in the foreach, but all that seems to do is add loads of records to m daily sales, when all I want is one row with an updated total.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out I was changing the d ( the daily sales table) instead of changing the " var r"

```
            DailySale d = new DailySale();
            var query = (from q in cont.DailySales where q.Date.Equals(Date) select q);


            foreach (var z in query)
            {
                counter++;
            }


            if (counter>0)
            {
                foreach (var r in query)
                {

                    r.Takings = r.Takings + (decimal)price; //  here i was using d instead of r
                    r.Profit = r.Takings - r.Expenses;
                }
                cont.SubmitChanges();
```

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `DailySale d = new DailySale();` into the scope(s) where it is used.

Comment: If you read the question you may notice that your answer doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding same object for each turn in foreach statement.

1) You can move this lines outside of foreach :

```
                    cont.DailySales.InsertOnSubmit(d);// update the value
                    cont.SubmitChanges();
```

2) Insert the object in first turn. Update same object in following turns.

```
                    cont.UpdateObject(d);
                    cont.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: UpdateObject isn't an option , it doesn't pop up... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should insert only once

```
 using (transactionClassDataContext cont = new transactionClassDataContext())
            { 
                int counter = 0;
                DailySale d = new DailySale();
                cont.DailySales.InsertOnSubmit(d);// **INSERT** the value
```

And update the rest of the times

```
            var query = (from q in cont.DailySales where q.Date.Equals(Date) select q);
            var query2 = (from r in cont.Transactions where r.Date.Equals(Date) select r);
            foreach (var z in query)
            {
                counter++;

            }
            if (counter>0)
            {

                    foreach (var y in query2)
                    {

                        takings = takings + y.Price;
                        Expenses = Expenses + 0;

                        d.Expenses += 0;
                        d.Takings += y.Price;
                        d.Profit = d.Takings - d.Expenses;
                        d.Date = Date;


                        cont.SubmitChanges(); // ***  left it here but better move it outside the foreach, 

                    }
```

The   `cont.SubmitChanges(); can even be moved completely to the end so you have only one transaction.